# Premiere control with mouse wheel

Tags: premiere

In Premiere Pro, there are many places where mouse pointer gets a two-sided arrow:

[image]

It took me quite a while to figure out I have to click-and-hold while panning to adjust these "sliders".

Is there a way to recofingure Premiere to allow me to use the wheel, without any clicking while I'm hovering over some of these controls?